# How to assign a static IP address to my VMWare machine?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-fusion

I currently have two VMWare Fusion VMs setup on my development machine. The first one (Windows Server 2003) has a static IP address, and I am using my hosts file to direct certain URLs to it.

I would like to do something similar with my second VM (Windows Server 2008), but I can't find any way to assign a static IP address anywhere in the settings.

How can I go about assigning a specific IP address to my second VM?

Comment: You assign a static IP in the VM exactly the same way you would **assign a static IP as if it had been a physical machine**.  When it comes to VMs you can and should ignore the fact that it is a VM 95% of the time.

Answer (score 5):

From the "Start" menu search for "View Network Connections".   The dialog that opens should show you a list of your network adapters.  Right click on the connection you want to configure and select "Properties."  From the next dialog double-click on the "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)" entry to configure the IPv4 addresses.

Comment: So I should be doing this on the Virtual Machine itself?

Comment: Yes.... but you need to be sure you have your network adapter setup correctly on the VM.  You should probably be using a bridged or host-only adapter, not a NAT.

Comment: Alternatively, if you use a bridged network adapter, you could probably setup a static lease in your router for your VM, if you have access to the router that is (this is what I do on my own network, its much easier to manage all static IPs in one place rather than on the individual machines).