# How can I get VMware Fusion to give a static IP to an Ubuntu guest?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, nat, vmware-fusion

I looked at [How to assign a static IP address to my VMWare machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/686540/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-to-my-vmware-machine) and didn't find an answer:

I am running VMware Fusion on Mavericks with an Ubuntu Saucy guest, the guest connected to the network via NAT. I want to shell into the guest and browse a Django site I am developing. But every ?few hours?, the guest IP changes, disrupting my ssh connections.

How do I ask the host's VMware Fusion (?or the guest?) to assign and stay with a static IP for the guest? t

--EDIT--

```
root@ubuntu:/home/christos/dashboard# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:86:f7:de  
          inet addr:172.16.144.203  Bcast:172.16.144.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe86:f7de/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8938 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4875 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:873521 (873.5 KB)  TX bytes:890704 (890.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:581528 (581.5 KB)  TX bytes:581528 (581.5 KB)
```

Comment: please post the output of ifconfig on the guest

Answer (score 1):

You do it as if this were a real machine. It depends on the OS, but in Ubuntu all you have to do is to replace, in the file */etc/network/interfaces*, these two lines

```
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

with these:

```
   auto eth0 
   iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.7
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254
    dns-nameservers 8.8.4.4 8.8.8.8
    up ip route add default via 192.168.1.254 
    down ip route del default via 192.168.1.254
```

This stanza is suitable for one of my pcs, which means you will have to adapt address, gateway, netmask, dns nameservers. As for the up/down lines, they automatically set up your routing table, you will have to substitute the IP address of your gateway.

Comment: Thank you; it keeps the specified address with my 172.x.x.x adaptation. It now loads and serves ssh and the Django application. Is this a sign I've used the wrong VMware network?